# Selenium exception when attempting to click ID of a button

Tags: java, testing, selenium, click

I'm attempting to use the Java Selenium client with JBehave to interact with a simple web page as a demonstration of BDD techniques.

When running the test, i'm trying to do a simple

`selenium.click("joinButton");`

but i'm getting a

`(com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: joinButton is not defined)`

exception thrown.

I've tried qualifying the ID as a dom ID using `id=joinButton`, as a css selector and even as xpath but to no avail.

The element is definitely rendered in the page.  I'm clearly doing something daft here.

Any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the relevant DOM snippet you're trying to click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised what the issue was here.  The Selenium class was being extended, and the click method overridden to only accept CSS selectors.  With this cruft now removed, the operation works as expected.

Thanks for your help folks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `waitForPageToLoad()` after navigating to the page in Selenium?  I'm betting your DOM hasn't loaded yet when your `click` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that while verifying with xpath and css you used  `selenium.click("//[@id=joinButton]")` and `selenium.click("css=#joinButton")` respectively.

You can also keep `selenium.isElementPresent("joinButton")` in a loop until some timeout (30/60 sec) and the moment selenium finds this element, it would come out of this loop and execute click command.